# Archive submission and validation disabled on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: 1]

It says "Distribution requires enrolment in the Apple Developer Program". When I click that link, it takes me to my valid, up to date, logged in, apple developer program account.

When I click preferences > account, I see my account there along with provisioning files, etc, and everything looks fine.

I have a valid iOS App Archive and an apple developer account.

Why are these buttons disabled for me? How do I get XCode to recognize my apple developer account?

Edit:

I just realized that on my accounts page my membership is listed as FREE. It is not free though, I payed for this already. Why is my account listed as FREE?

[image]

Comment: Is the proper account/team selected in your project? Click on the project (top of the organizer in the left pane), then the target, then the General tab, and check the Identity -> Team popup.

Comment: Didn't your account expire?

Answer (score 0):

I had to choose the agent account, and then connect a device to my computer in order to create the provisioning files.

Thanks for the help.